# Storing a user's code in a combo box that calls out for its name when selected

Tags: qml

I want to make two input text fields (let's call them X and Y) that are in page A,

X: code of the person, Y: name of the person,

Page A contains two text fields for input, and a combo box for selection (for delete purpose), an adding button, and a delete button,

Once the X and Y are filled in the text fields they are inputed using an 'add' button, I want them to be stored when the button is pressed so I can call them back in the page B, or in the combo box in page A,

Page B contains a combo box and a casual text output next to it, the X goes to the combo box, and the Y goes to the text that both are in page B

When I select in page B one X of the many X that already have been inputed, I want the text to change with what have been selected accordingly,

if I want to delete one of the X, I do so by selecting the combobox that exists in Page A and proceed pressing the delete button,

how to store both the X and Y in variables and insert them in comboboxes and the texts, and make a bond between them, connecting each name with its own code ?

**PageA**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.14

Item {
    id:pageA
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    property alias codeIn: code.text
    property alias nameIn: name.text
TextField{
    id:code
    y: 0
    width: 200
    height: 50
    placeholderText: qsTr("Type the code here")
}

TextField{
    id:name
    x: 0
    y: 65
    width: 200
    height: 50
    placeholderText: qsTr("Type the name here")
}
ComboBox{
    id:selectionForDelete
    x: 320
    y: 65
    width: 200
    height: 50
}

Button{
    id:adding
    x: 29
    y:155
    text: "add"
    onClicked: {
        code.clear()
        name.clear()
    }

}
Button{
    id:deleting
    x: 355
    y: 155
    text: "delete"
  }
}
```

**PageB**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.14    
Item {
    id:pageB
    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    ComboBox{
        id:codeList
    }

    Text {
        id: relatedName
        y:70
        text: qsTr("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple solution is to declare a `ListModel` in your main app and when you instantiate either `PageA` or `PageB` they will have read/write access to the `ListModel`.

```
//MainApp.qml
Page {
    ListModel { id: listModel }
    PageA { }
    PageB { }
}
//PageA.qml
Page {
}
//PageB.qml
Page {
}
```

As an example, PageA gives the ability to add new users as well as delete existing users, whereas PageB gives the ability to search for existing users:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        PageA {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
        PageB {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        function appendUser(code, name) { append( { code, name } ); }
    }
}

//PageA.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Frame {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text { text: qsTr("PageA") }
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Users") }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: listModel
            delegate: Frame {
                width: ListView.view.width
                RowLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    Text {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        text: model.code + " " + model.name
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: qsTr("Delete")
                        onClicked: listModel.remove(model.index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Create new user") }
        TextField {
            id: code
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            placeholderText: qsTr("Code")
        }
        TextField {
            id: name
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            placeholderText: qsTr("Text")
        }
        Button {
            enabled: code.text && name.text
            text: qsTr("Add")
            onClicked: listModel.appendUser(code.text, name.text)
        }
    }
}
//PageB.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Frame {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text { text: qsTr("PageB") }
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Select Code") }
        ComboBox {
            id: comboBox
            model: listModel
            textRole: "code"
            valueRole: "name"
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Selected Name") }
        Text {
            text: comboBox.currentValue ?? ""
        }
        Item {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Layouts%201.15%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20RowLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PageA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.preferredWidth%3A%20200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PageB%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.preferredWidth%3A%20200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20ListModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20listModel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20appendUser(code%2C%20name)%20%7B%20append(%20%7B%20code%2C%20name%20%7D%20)%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FPageA.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Layouts%201.15%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ColumnLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22PageA%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Users%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ListView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20listModel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delegate%3A%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20ListView.view.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RowLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20parent.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20model.code%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20model.name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Delete%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onClicked%3A%20listModel.remove(model.index)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Create%20new%20user%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TextField%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholderText%3A%20qsTr(%22Code%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TextField%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholderText%3A%20qsTr(%22Text%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enabled%3A%20code.text%20%26%26%20name.text%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Add%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onClicked%3A%20listModel.appendUser(code.text%2C%20name.text)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%2F%2FPageB.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Layouts%201.15%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ColumnLayout%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Frame%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillWidth%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22PageB%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Select%20Code%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ComboBox%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20comboBox%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20listModel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20textRole%3A%20%22code%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20valueRole%3A%20%22name%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Label%20%7B%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Selected%20Name%22)%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20comboBox.currentValue%20%3F%3F%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Layout.fillHeight%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: That actually do cuts right straight into the butter, thx for your awnser, I really appreciate it.